# lisp format string that consumes one argument and prints in multiple directive places

Tags: lisp, string-formatting

I want to do this

```
(format nil "One occurence of ~X , another one: ~X , and yet another one: ~X" #\some-char)
```

Is there any X format directive that can do this?

Comment: btw in such cases where i post a question and after STFW I find the answer almost immediately, should i delete the question or leave it?

Comment: Although your answer is indeed sourced from the first hit on Google for my search, which was "insert a string at multiple places with common lisp format", I didn't click that link but instead ended up on this answer.  It was the seventh hit, but the title of your question makes the content so clear this question/answer is now IMHO the most convenient reference online for this particular info. (As seems frequently to be the case with Stackoverflow questions that people want to close or even have closed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it: It is  `~:*` It tells lisp to reuse the last argument. Like rewinding the arguments one place back.

For the whole explanation paragraph see: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html (it is near the bottom of the page)

So it becomes

```
(format nil "One occurence of ~C , another one: ~:*~C , and yet another one: ~:*~C" #\a)
=> "One occurence of a , another one: a , and yet another one: a"
```